# Trying to add local IP to Azure PostgreSQL server but getting getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: azure, azure-postgresql

I'm using Azure App Service which created an Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server and I keep getting this error when trying to add my local IP to the firewall throught the Azure extension on VSCode:
[image: Error]

This is a screenshot of the server name from the Azure portal:
[image: server name from azure portal]

I tried setting the Azure portal to public through "Network Connectivity" but the option is disabled for some reason:
[image: Network Connectivity]

What is my best course of action for being able to connect to my server through my client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-firewall-rules), firewall rules specify allowed public IP address ranges. The firewall grants access to the server based on the originating IP address of each request. A firewall rule will be created when public access is enabled in the networking section of the database. With [private access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking#private-access-vnet-integration), no public endpoint is available, and only hosts located on the same network can access Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server. Therefore, you should enable public access to the database while creating the server as shown below. However, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-networking), it is not possible to change the networking option once the server is created.

[image]

Add the client IP address by creating a firewall rule as shown below:

[image]

You will then be able to connect to the database through the client successfully, as shown below:

[image]